# I need help coming over error, undefined object stops the code from running

Tags: javascript, local-storage

**the code works in safari live server, but not in chrome, and not on live website either
its suppose to save the active color or disabled color on the icons**

```
const currentState = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("selectionState") || '{}');

const getKeyType = el => {
  return [el.parentNode.id, el.dataset.type];
}

const populateState = el => {
  [key, type] = getKeyType(el);

  el.style.color = currentState[key][type] ? el.dataset.activeColor : el.dataset.disabledColor;  
};

const clickity = function () {
  [key, type] = getKeyType(this);
  
  if (!currentState.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    currentState[key] = {type: false};
  }
  
  currentState[key][type] = !currentState[key][type];
  populateState(this);
  
  localStorage.setItem("selectionState", JSON.stringify(currentState));
}

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("i");

for (const button of buttons) {
  populateState(button);
  button.addEventListener('click', clickity);
}
```

and I get this error

```
 TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'currentState[key][type]')
```

Comment: Seems like currentState  object is undefined can you please make sure this variable (currentState ) has data in it ?

Comment: You initialize the object as an empty object `{}` prior to doing anything with `localStorage` - therefore, every time `localStorage` doesn't have a value for `selectionState`, you will see this error. You'll need to refactor this so that `currentState`'s data structure can be used consistently.

Comment: Im sorry, but I have tried giving currentstate a object. but I can't figure it out. where or what should I give as key and type value?